# code coverage to know how much code has been tested

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, code-coverage

We are writing JUnit tests for our java web application. Initially we were unable to find how much code is tested in the calling method, after that we include some code coverage plug-in in the eclipse. I followed the below procedure to run and know the code coverage.

- Right click on the test class
- Select Coverage As - > Junit test

The above procedure is giving the result in the 'Coverage' tab in the eclipse with the percentage. The problem here is like it is giving the entire report of the module even if i run only one test.
Is this report proper?
How can we know exactly how much code test method is covered?

Comment: Code coverage is one measurement only; it does not tell the whole story! Try and do some mutation testing as well. With Java you can do this with [pitest](https://github.com/hcoles/pitest)

Comment: Doesn't the coverage tab details the instruction coverage per file / class / method?  At least in the past I have used a plugin that did so.